# Why can't I download 2 different files from same page ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, webforms, memorystream

I am using these 2 functions to download 2 different files from a single page.

RenderReport is used to download an rdlc report been sent to it i.e. LocalReport and the DOWNLOAD() is used to download a pdf file.

Now the problem is that one of them works not both. If I download the RDLC report then pdf download doesn't work or the reverse. It throws exception i.e. browser detected duplicate header etc.

```
  public void Download() 
    {
        try
        {
            MemoryStream memStream = Export(html); // returns a memory stream object
            byte[] bytesInStream = memStream.ToArray();
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.Headers.Remove("content-disposition");
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;    filename=name_you_file.pdf");

            Response.BinaryWrite(bytesInStream);
            Response.End();
            Response.Flush();

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }



    private void RenderReport(LocalReport localReport)
    {
        try
        {

            //Give the collection a name (EmployeeCollection) so that we can reference it in our report designer

            var reportType = "PDF";
            string mimeType;
            string encoding;
            string fileNameExtension;


            var deviceInfo =
                string.Format("<DeviceInfo><OutputFormat>{0}</OutputFormat><PageWidth>8.27in</PageWidth><PageHeight>11.69in</PageHeight><MarginTop>0.3in</MarginTop><MarginLeft>0.3in</MarginLeft><MarginRight>0.3in</MarginRight><MarginBottom>0.3in</MarginBottom></DeviceInfo>", reportType);

            Warning[] warnings;
            string[] streams;


            //Render the report
            var renderedBytes = localReport.Render(
                reportType,
                deviceInfo,
                out mimeType,
                out encoding,
                out fileNameExtension,
                out streams,
                out warnings);

            //Clear the response stream and write the bytes to the outputstream
            //Set content-disposition to "attachment" so that user is prompted to take an action
            //on the file (open or save)
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = mimeType;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Tender." + fileNameExtension);
            Response.BinaryWrite(renderedBytes);
            Response.End();
            Response.Flush();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: isn't that clear "detected duplicate header" ?

Comment: @Aristos the solution ? I tried everything i could

Comment: what do you mean does not work ? any error or control is not going to that method ??